# LARAVEL: How to use middleware on named routes

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I've been working on an app that initially didn't use middleware. Later on, I decided to add middleware and had to change my routes from something like:

```
Route::get('admin/poems', array('as' => 'poems', 'uses' =>      'PoemsController@poem'));
```

to

```
Route::get('admin/poem', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'PoemsController@poem']);
```

Now the disadvantage is that I had been redirecting to this route (`poems`) several times and adding middleware as indicated will require me to go through all my code and change the name of the route in the redirect.
How do i solve this problem?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to lose the name of your route, the array will still accept it along with your middleware.

Just add it in to look like so:

```
Route::get('admin/poem', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'as' => 'poems', 'uses' => 'PoemsController@poem']);
```

This way you don't need to go through and rename your routes anywhere and can still protect it with auth middleware.

Answer (score 0):

try put middleware to a  group route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```